# How to remove untracked files in GIT without git clean

Tags: git

How do i remove untracked files? I have tried almost every variation of git clean [i.e. git clean -f -d -n -x] and tried git stash save --include-untracked
but the files are still that. Any suggestions?

```
$ git st 
On branch abc 

Untracked files: 
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) 
           meow/ 
           woof_001
```

Comment: If they're not tracked, you can just delete them the normal way, you don't need to involve git at all.

Comment: `git clean -fd` helps?

Comment: What’s the output of `git clean -id`? It should list files it’s going to try to clean.

Comment: If they are generated by your build, you can add them to .gitignore as well

Comment: You can't say "I've tried all these things and it didn't work" without showing us explicitly what you've tried and the exact result. Also note that `st` isn't a valid git subcommand; while we can intuit what you meant based on the output, it's always best to use the full command in questions rather than aliases (what if `git st` is `git stash` for someone else?).

Comment: Hi All, thanks. but as jonrsharpe suggested, deleting it the normal way is the easiest. @Ryan git clean -id lists other files but weirdly did not present the untracked files that I'm trying to ignore

Answer (score 7):

I just came across your question when I was having a similar problem. My problem turned out to be that I was not in the top-level folder of the project when I was typing the git commands.

in this situation it seems 'git status' will list all the untracked files inside your working copy, but git clean will not process anything outside your current directory

Answer (score 1):

Untracked files are files that exist only on the file system of your local machine in a folder that has a .git directory. Any git command to attempt to remove them from the index won't do anything as they don't exist in the index.  Git is not indexing ("tracking") them yet and therefore doesn't know about them.

There are a few options available to you depending on the nature of the files.

**Generated Files**

If they are files generated by your IDE, or binaries (like bin/ or obj/) then you probably don't want to commit them to source control.  You should add entries to a .gitignore file that is committed to your source control at the repository root so it has effect over your entire repository.  [Here](https://github.com/github/gitignore) are some good examples of .gitignore files.

**Files you really don't want to keep**

You can either:

1. Delete them from your file system; or
2. Move the file(s) to somewhere other than the folder (or any if its subfolders) containing the .git folder.

BTW: git stash will only work on files that have first been added.  A stash needs to be given a name and is the same idea as "shelving" or "shelvesets" and allows you to share changes with another person without committing the changes to a branch per se.

Answer (score 1):

please use command "git clean -d -f"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer suggests trying something that was listed as having been tried in the OP.